# How to know derived class which method is called/executed from the base class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class called **logIT**

```
public class LogIT
{
    public string strMessage = string.Empty;
    public string strClassName = string.Empty;
    public string strMethodName = string.Empty;
    public LogIT()
    {
        strMethodName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
        strClassName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
    }
}
```

Another class which inherits the LogIT class named "**product**"

```
public class Product : LogIT
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
    public void GetProduct()
    {

    }

    public void AddEditProduct()
    {

    }
}
```

THis is my **main** method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product objProduct = new Product();
        objProduct.GetProduct();
    }
```

My question is, when i call the **product** class's **GetProduct** method, i want **logit** class constructor to be called and known which method of **dervied** class has been called.

Please suggest how to accomplish it or any other alternative for the same.
Thanks

Comment: But... once you call `GetProduct`, the `LogIT` constuctor is already finished...

Comment: Yes thats right so is ther any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the weirdest code I've seen so far...

The constructor is executed only once, when you instantiate the Product class.

Try using the following code instead:

```
public class LogIT
{
    public string strMessage = string.Empty;
    public string strClassName = string.Empty;
    public string strMethodName = string.Empty; 

    public void LogStackTrace()
    {
        strMethodName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
        strClassName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
    }
}

public class Product : LogIT
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
    public void GetProduct()
    {
        base.LogStackTrace();
    }

    public void AddEditProduct()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen a lot weirder. This *is* Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hah! Touché, indeed. (Piling on words to meet the minimum requirement of comment length)

Comment: so for each and every derived class method i have to call base method..?

Comment: That's what I've would have done, or you can also use Attributes on method level. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx